# Kivy + 3D - only 65535 indicies allowed. Can i handle this?

Tags: python, opengl, opengl-es, kivy, opengl-es-2.0

According to [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.html#kivy.graphics.Mesh), there can be only 65535 indicies in index buffer. This is really sensible and painful limit for 3d graphics today. So, my question is - is it possible to handle this somehow? For example, change something in source code? And is this *really* OpenGL ES 2.0 limitation?

There is actually bad solution to this problem - split draw calls, and set vertex and index buffer separately for every 65535 verticies in 3d model, but it is really a strike on performace, since some of the verticies will need to be copied between different parts of the splitted buffer.

I will be really grateful to someone who will explain me where can i find this part of kivy code and change it, or explain, why i can't change it, if i really can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to

> OpenGL ES Common Profile Specification Version 2.0.25 (Full
>   Specification) (November 2, 2010)

the indices must

> be one of UNSIGNED_BYTE or UNSIGNED_SHORT, indicating that the values
>   in indices are indices of GL type ubyte or ushort, respectively.

So, as long as `Kivy`is using `OpenGL 2`, I think you are stuck with that limitation.

In OpenGL 3.3, that restriction is that the indices:

> must be one of UNSIGNED_BYTE, UNSIGNED_SHORT, or UNSIGNED_INT,
>   indicating that the index values are of GL type ubyte, ushort, or uint
>   respectively.

Comment: I've checked it. Thank tou. God, that is stupid, but thanks a lot anyway. So, isn't there any solution to this?

Comment: As far as I know, the only solution is what you mentioned in your post. You can get the best performance by following the advice in the `kivy` [documentation](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.graphics.html?highlight=pushmatrix#kivy.graphics.Mesh): `numpy arrays, python arrays etc. are used in place, without creating any additional copies. However, the buffers cannot be readonly (even though they are not changed, due to a cython limitation) and must be contiguous in memory.`

Answer (score 2):

If your GL ES implementation supports the [`OES_element_index_uint`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/extensions/OES/OES_element_index_uint.txt) extension you're free to use `GL_UNSIGNED_INT` for indexes.

Comment: I think it does, but i need help of how can i enable it for Kivy. I've searched in source code a lot, but there is no such an opportunity, at least i didn't found anything

Comment: Nothing to enable really.  If `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` contains `GL_OES_element_index_uint` you're good to go.

Comment: But when it doesn't?

Comment: Then you're SOL & need to chop your geometry up into multiple calls.

Comment: Think it's time to change framework... Thank you though

Answer (score 1):

> I will be really grateful to someone who will explain me where can i find this part of kivy code and change it

Further to the other answers, there's nothing that really fundamentally limits Kivy to OpenGL ES 2, so it probably isn't that hard to use features from newer versions if you want. However, you probably won't find someone to simply give you a diff. You'll need to look into the [Kivy graphics code](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/tree/master/kivy/graphics) and possibly extend the opengl cython wrappers.

Comment: Oh, i did. You're right about that. It is hard and long for me to find and change it alone. I think for my purposes it will be better to use raw OpenGL + ImGui. Thanks anyway!